# Как получить Html из буфера обмена в формате Unicode?

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка, utf-8, unicode

Программа берет содержание буфера, в котором хранится HTML, и должна сделать над ним какую-то работу.

Но проблема в том, что в нем кириллица и нужно что-то делать с кодировкой…

Пробовал перекодировать, но у некоторых пользователей возникают кракозябры:

```
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source);         
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Пробовал HTML из буфера, который иногда вызывает кракозябры, сам прогонять через программу и у меня всё нормально.

Может дело в каких-то настройках Windows?

Какие существуют более универсальные варианты перекодирования?

Все пользователи (в том числе и я) используют Google Chrome, а значит, что это не проблема браузера.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Понятие кодировки возникает только при сохранении строки на диск (в виде отдельных байт) или при передачи по сети (в виде байт).

То, что вы считаете ситуацией "строка `source` в неправильной кодировке" - это ложная проблема. Т.к. проблема кодировки возникает только при преобразовании в байты - то на самом деле ваша проблема это

"строка source была прочитана из массива байт с указанием неправильной кодировки".

И править надо это не "перекодированием". После прочтения строки из байт  с использованием неправильной кодировки нет 100% рабочего способа ее "исправить". Есть только костыли вроде "записать ее назад в байты с указанием неправильной кодировки (надеясь что байты получатся те же самые), а потом еще раз прочитать с указанием правильно". Т.е. вы пытаетесь построить цепочку:

1. Есть байты строки в кодировке A
2. Прочитать их как строку в кодировке B
3. Увидеть кракозяблы
4. Записать кракозяблы обратно с указанием кодировки B (использовать операцию, обратную (2) надеясь получить оригинальные байты, те же, что были в (1)
5. Прочитать байты (те же, что были в (1)) в строку, но уже с указанием кодировки A

Код в вашем примере делает пункты 3-5. Код для 1-2 вы не привели. При этом очевидно, что в полной цепочке пункты 2-4 избыточны, и выглядеть она как

1. Есть байты строки в кодировке A
2. Прочитать байты в строку с указанием кодировки A

Вам нужно исправить то место, где вы читаете `source` из массива байт/из сети/из буфера обмена, указав в нем правильную кодировку. "Перекодирование стоит использовать только в случае, если вы получаете кривую строку сразу в виде string из стороннего источника.

---

К сожалению, `Cliboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)` - это именно такой источник.

[HTML Clipboard Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015(v=vs.85).aspx) выдает содержимое в виде байт именно в UTF-8.

[Реализация чтения байт в HTML-строку в Cliboard выглядит вот так](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataObject.cs.html#1460):

```
if (format.Equals(DataFormats.Text)
    || format.Equals(DataFormats.Rtf)
    || format.Equals(DataFormats.OemText)) {
    data = ReadStringFromHandle(hglobal, false);
}
else if (format.Equals(DataFormats.Html)) {
    if (WindowsFormsUtils.TargetsAtLeast_v4_5) {
        data = ReadHtmlFromHandle(hglobal);
    }
    else {
        // This will return UTF-8 strings as an array of ANSI characters, which makes it the wrong behavior.
        // Since there are enough samples online how to workaround that, we will continue to return the
        // incorrect value to applications targeting netfx 4.0
        // DevDiv2 
        data = ReadStringFromHandle(hglobal, false);
    }
}
```

Собственно, комментарий полностью объясняет поведение.

- при компиляции под 4.5 и более поздние фреймворки вы получите сразу валидную строку
- при компиляции под 4.0 и более ранние версии - вы получите получите байты в UTF-8, прочитанные как `Encoding.Default`, через `new string((sbyte*)ptr)`

Соответственно, в <=4.0 ваш хак с перекодированием обязателен и полностью валиден. В >=4.5 он гаранитированно невалиден и избыточен.

Comment: а можно ли как-нибудь понять, что кодировка была выбрана некорректно? Я бы в таком случае перебирал все возможные кодировки, до тех пор, пока не получу нормальную информацию. Делом в том, что буферы на разных ПК разные=> указать 1 фиксированную кодировку, наверное, не получится, что бы у всех работало. Например, у меня работает пример выше, но у других он может не работать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 буферы на всех PK одинаковые. из буфера сразу можно читать unicode text - вызовом Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText). И не нужно ничего при этом перебирать.

Comment: Но тогда я потеряю структуру Html. А мне нужно работать именно с текстом, который в Html формате. Т.е обрамлен в теги и все такое.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну так и задавайте вопрос про вставку html из буфера обмена, а не про перекодировку.

Comment: @iluxa1810 тогда стоит явно об этом упомянуть в вопросе - потому что проблема перекодировки в общем случае неразрешима, но вот конкретно для TextDataFormat.Html такой костыль (с модификациями) вполне приемлем. Я добавлю костыль в ответ.

Comment: Вопрос поправил.

Comment: Странно, тогда непонятно, почему у некоторых мой способ работает, а у некоторых нет...

Comment: @iluxa1810 дописал с цитатами из исходников. там зависит от версии .NET, под которую вы собираете. Поднимайте минимальную версию до 4.5 - и все заработает.

Comment: @PashaPash, а может ли использовать 4,5 фреймворк, если я собрал под 4,0 ? У меня подозрение, что кракозябры связаны именно с избыточным перекодированием... Но у кого-то работает корректно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Проверка из исходников WinForms именно на этот случай и делается: она определяет какую версию фреймворка программа запрашивает.